# Jmeter freezes with a CPU of 100%

Tags: jmeter

I have been working on some test cases using jmeter.  For the past month its been working fine but now when I run a test (even old previously used one's which worked).   The GUI freezes and the CPU is 100%.  I have not changed anything different so I am really stumped as to what has happened.  I suspect a log file or temp file is full but I do not know of any?  Can someone help

Answer (score 5):

**Don't use GUI for running load tests**. JMeter GUI is designed for tests development and debugging only. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
```

Once test run is complete you can launch JMeter GUI and open `results.jtl` with the listener of your choice.

Other things to consider:

- use latest versions of JMeter, Java and [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)
- increase Java Heap space allocated to JMeter. Default is 512MB which is not enough for running an immense load test
- disable all the listeners during test run
- use pre/post processors and assertions only where required

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for detailed information on above and few more JMeter tips and tweaks.

Comment: In that case consider buying a better CPU or [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: Do you mean a new computer? Higher RAM?

Comment: I have a system with 4GB as ram. and i think that's enough to create and debug the script.when i am running a simple script CPU utilization increase to 60%. I increased the Heap size also.
And one thing i am using mac.Please provide me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, I set the log level to NONE and it was solved